# Using PHP, how can I get the element holding the visit ID from the corresponding row in the HTML table?

Tags: php, html, dom

I have an HTML table that fills its data from a table in the database, there's an approve button for the admin to approve the visit and change its status to APPROVED, I need to know how I can be able to select element holding the ID, so I can query on the visits and edit its 'STATUS' attribute

[HTML table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XUP3.png)

Here's the code inserting the table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Request Num</th>
            <th scope="col">Visitor Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Car Number</th>
            <th scope="col">Visit Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Approve</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        if ($_SESSION['sess_flag'] == 1) {
            $getVisits = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM Visit");
            $getVisits->execute();
            $visits = $getVisits->fetchAll();
            foreach ($visits as $visit) {
                echo "          <tr>
                <th scope='row' class='id'>". $visit['VISIT_ID'] ."</th>
                <td>". $visit['VISITOR_NAME'] ."</td>
                <td>". $visit['CAR_PLATE_NUMBER'] ."</td>
                <td>". $visit['VISIT_DATE'] ."</td>
                <td>". $visit['STATUS'] ."</td>
                <td>
                    <div class='icon-container'>
                        <i class='far fa-check-square icon'></i>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't using PHP. PHP is server-side. You'd need client-side Javascript to perform actions on the client. Look into AJAX if you want client-side data sent to the server

Comment: I know how to get the element using JQuery, but how can I use it then to make an SQL query to change the STATUS attribute in the corresponding visit row?

Comment: Use a `<form>` to send data to the server (reloads the page) or https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/ to send data asynchronously

Comment: bind an event handler to the checkbox that sends an ajax request to the server - with the ID & status as data parameters for the request

Answer (score 0):

You could add a link like this that will send the VISIT_ID as an query parameter "id" to "page.php":

```
<div class='icon-container'>
    <a href="page.php?id=". $visit['VISIT_ID'] ."><i class='far fa-check-square icon'></i></a>
</div>
```

On "page.php" check

```
if( ! empty($_GET["id"]) { 
    $id = $_GET["id"];

    // Update database...
}
```